# How can I append a wav file using scipy.io.wavfile?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am creating a simple program that generates wav files of multiple sine waves. As is, the wav file will be written over instead of appended but I haven't been able to find append in the scipy.io.wavfile documentation. I did find one other user asking this here on SO but the answer given was that this is default behavior, but it doesn't work this way for me. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.io import wavfile


duration = 10  # in seconds, may be float
f = 200  # sine frequency, Hz, may be float
fs=48000
samples = (np.sin(2 * np.pi * np.arange(fs * duration) * f / fs)).astype(np.float32)

wavfile.write('Sine.wav', 48000, samples)


duration = 10  # in seconds, may be float
f = 100  # sine frequency, Hz, may be float
fs=48000
samples = (np.sin(2 * np.pi * np.arange(fs * duration) * f / fs)).astype(np.float32)

wavfile.write('Sine.wav', 48000, samples)
```

This code results in a 10 second 100hz sine .wav file, where I want a 20 second wav file with 10 seconds of 200hz then 10 seconds of 100hz

Answer (score 1):

You can append the 2 sample arrays together, I used 400Hz for the second sample because 100Hz is not audible on my computer speakers.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.io import wavfile


duration = 10  # in seconds, may be float
f = 200  # sine frequency, Hz, may be float
fs=48000
samples1 = (np.sin(2 * np.pi * np.arange(fs * duration) * f / fs)).astype(np.float32)

#wavfile.write('Sine.wav', 48000, samples)


duration = 10  # in seconds, may be float
f = 400  # sine frequency, Hz, may be float
fs=48000
samples2 = (np.sin(2 * np.pi * np.arange(fs * duration) * f / fs)).astype(np.float32)
samples=np.append(samples1,samples2)
wavfile.write('Sine.wav', 48000, samples)
```

Comment: This works great until the file is too large and I run out of ram, that's why I was looking to append to file. Do you have any suggestions on that front? This trick is very helpful for me otherwise, thanks for your help!